# Cant ssh to my public ip

Tags: linux, ssh, fedora, connection

I have been able to log on to my dev box (which is in my home network) for a while now, using ssh username@publicip however recently this has become impossible due to the following error

> ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer

Whats strange is, if i use the network address instead of the public address I am able to connect with no issues.

My colleague is also able to SSH to the public ip address with no issues as well.

What could be the cause of this and how can I solve it? I did a quick google which suggested I look in my etc/hosts.deny file, however I don't have one.

Thanks

Comment: By "public address" and "network address" you mean that you're using the external facing IP address vs. the internal facing IP address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using rsa key authentication, you might want to make sure the authorized_keys file hasn't been recently modified on the dev server.

If all else fails, you can run sshd in debug mode `sshd -d` and then ssh connect from your client terminal.  This will print out a lot of information.  Search for errors/failures in the output.

To do this:

1. `sudo service sshd stop` # don't worry, your active ssh connections will not be terminated, only new connections will be affected.
2. `/usr/sbin/sshd -d`
   ... puts out debug info...
3. from the client terminal (your workstation), connect to the dev server via ssh using the -v option (verbose): `ssh -v user@host.com`
4. read through the debug info on the `sshd -d` output and the ssh client verbose output
5. -- fix issue --
6. Ctrl-C to exit the `sshd -d`" to exit debug.
7. `sudo service sshd start` # restart sshd daemon

Comment: If you're using rsa key authentication, you might want to make sure the authorized_keys file hasn't been recently modified on the dev server. - this is exactly what had happened. thanks

Comment: How would a change to `authorized_keys` cause a connection reset? As far as `service sshd stop`, it is true that you can usually run that without affecting established connections, however I have seen systems where running that command twice will kill all established ssh connections.

Comment: I've seen this before where someone used Putty to generate keys and did a copy-n-paste to the UNIX/LINUX system with line breaks.  This corrupted the authorized_keys file and gave the *connection reset by peer* error.   I would agree that you need to use extreme caution when stopping sshd as to not lock yourself (or others) out.  As a rule, NEVER CLOSE ACTIVE SESSIONS while sshd has been stopped.  You may not be able to get back in.  If you have cpanel (or similar), you can restart the service of http.

Answer (score 1):

Can you test a ping to your host?  It could be resolving incorrectly.  If this is the case, you may want to check the TTL on the DNS, or to manually resolve it set the following line in your /etc/hosts where your IP address is x.x.x.x and your host is yourhost.com

```
x.x.x.x yourhost.com
```